# creating a new button or making it appear in an if statement in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using c# 2008 and i want to know if its possible to create(or display) a new button in an if statement after something happened.  eg. if a certain label displays text, then a button must be created.  If anyone can help, it will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: This is so trivial that I think you can solve it yourself such as by starting with some search or look in some book? The important thing is **you should have some logic in your head, think out some related keywords and search for solution**.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Now, what have you tried? How far have you got, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This code show you how to create and display a new button when double click mouse on the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button button1 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1 == null)
        {
            button1 = new Button();
            button1.Text = "New Button";
            button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
            button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);
            button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(button1);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button clicked.");
    }
}
```

Note: `this.Controls.Add(button1);` add the button1 to the Form1. You also using this `Controls` property of other control to add a control to another control.

See more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I think this answers the trivial part of the question, although it's correct. the OP is asking to create a button after something happens, if a label displays some text for example. So the answer is not so easy as it seems. I've been thinking about it and maybe in the Idle event of the application.

Comment: We can create a button after something happens with the same way like above. (Ex: when a label displays some text for example)

Comment: Yes, your answer was correct as I said. But I think it does not fullfill the OP question. May be that'all she/he wants.